# Android Facebook SDK FriendPickerFragment search option

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the great FriendPickerFragment provided but Facebook SDK for Android.

It actually a great tool that saves me a lot of time, but it does miss 1 important functionality.

I have lots of friends in Facebook (more than a 1000) and i could use a search text box to filter friends by name.

is there any native way for doing this in the native SDK ? isn't that weird if there isn't ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i'm using the native FriendPickerFragment and it works.. but it has no search field... i can build one of my own, but i'm trying to be spoiled and use the native's  Fragment

Comment: Assaf, I think you should accept my answer. You asked if there is a way to do that - and I answer it perciely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any native way for doing this in the native SDK ?

Unfortunately, with the current Facebook android latest SDK, without extending and modifying some parts in it source code, the answer is - **no**.

the is no way to configure `FriendPickerFragment` to be with edit text for search filter, or any other way to tell it to open itself with filtered results.

how do I know it for sure? - [`I studied it source code!`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android).  there is nothing secret under the hood..

I guess that's not the answer you were looking for, but that's the true.

by the way - I didn't find `FriendPickerFragment` that great at all - the list view scrolling works terrible on devices that are not with "top of the technology specs", because they are probably blocking the UI thread to do the image decoding .. so I implemented it myself as you probably know how to do...

comment:  the [facebook SDK source code is availible](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk), and I guess that if you really want - you can extend (or completly modify) `FriendPickerFragment` class source code to be whatever you want. for example, extend GraphObjectAdapter.java. that's the base Adapter class been used by the FriendPickerFragment's `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a broad question, but I'll tell you the concept/flow. Actually its quite simple-

- Make the API call: `/me/friends?fields={desired_fields}`. You can test your API calls in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=)
- Then save all the friends info
- Implement search.

Quite simple, right?

Comment: Maybe my question wasnt clear.. i know how to use the graph api. As i mantioned, im using Facebook SDK and FriendPickerFragment which does the api call for me and show a list of all my friends... what i dont know if there is a NATIVE way in the SDK to show a searchbar in this Fragment...